# Can I access the vue-router parser manually?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Can I get access to the vue-router parser so that I can evaluate a link before navigating to it? That is:

Let's say I have the path `/one/two/three` but that is *not* the current path. I'd like to see if that path matches something in my route file and get the object that it matches.

For example, let's say the above path would match:

```
{
  path: `/one/:user/:page`,
  name: "path-one",
  component: () => import('../views/DashboardPage.vue'),
  meta: { etc... }
},
```

I'd like to call something like:

```
const match = useRouter().parse("/one/two/three")
```

and have `match` be the structure above.

I'm guessing that function exists in the router, but I couldn't see that it is publicly exposed.

Another way of asking this, is I want the results of `useRoute` but for an arbitrary URL, not have it use the current path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [resolve](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#resolve) function on useRouter. a RouteLocation object is returned, which will have a `matched` property containing matching Route Records from your routes file.

```js
const matches = useRouter().resolve("/one/two/three").matched // empty array if no matches
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! I missed it in the docs and only found it when I searched directly for "resolve"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with match:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

const match = router.match('/one/two/three')
console.log(match) // This will log the matched route record
```